# can not get flash object in html, even if with swfObject.js

Tags: javascript, html, flash, null

Sorry for my poor English. ><

I encountered a problem that I can not get swf Object from my html file with javascript.

Here is my swf object code in Html:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="direction" name="direction" align="middle" data="../static/swf/direction.swf" width="650" height="650">
    <param name="quality" value="high">
    <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff">
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="sameDomain">
    <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true">
</object>
```

and when I get this object with javascript(swfobject.js) below, it failed:

```
var flash = swfobject.getObjectById("direction");
console.log(flash);
```

The result is null.
But when I step into the method swfobject.getObjectById, which is:

```
function getObjectById(objectIdStr) {
    var r = null;
    var o = getElementById(objectIdStr);
    if (o && o.nodeName == "OBJECT") {
        if (typeof o.SetVariable != UNDEF) {
            r = o;
        }
        else {
            var n = o.getElementsByTagName(OBJECT)[0];
            if (n) {
                r = n;
            }
        }
    }
    return r;
}
```

after sentence "o = getElementById(objectIdStr);", o is exactly the Object mentioned before, but the result of "typeof o.SetVariable != UNDEF" is true, which results in that r is returned with null. Besides, I can confirm the DOM is loaded over.

So I do not know where did I do something wrong? Please help me! Thx!

Comment: I discovered that the flash object originally is "display: none"(actually its ancestor element is "display:none"), it does not load until it switches to "display: block", so my window.onload event is invalid.